# yii2вывод логотипа в NavVar

Tags: yii2

не отображается логотип, в чем беда?
  NavBar::begin([
         'brandLabel' => Html::img('1.png'),
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-static-top',
        ],
    ]);
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего не верный url к картинке